# Limit of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2}{n^x}$ when $x\to0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find limit of this series 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2}{n^x}$$ It's a Riemann series but I can't switch limit and sum and I don't know how to start. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What is this edit achieving? Masking the question? Please stop doing that.

Comment: AFAIK $\tan n\pi$ is zero, so the numerator in your series' terms is $\lceil\pi-\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\tan n\pi\rfloor\rceil = \lceil\pi-\lfloor 0\rfloor\rceil = \lceil\pi\rceil = 4$...  [That was a comment to this version of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1773991/2 ]

Comment: As already answered: the limit cannot exist as the infinite series doesn't converge for $x<1\;$

Comment: Can it be solved by Dirichlet regularization?

Comment: Did: Why you edit my question? It was much more interesting than after editing.

Comment: This need clearly to be (zeta or other)-regularized and [indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\;\zeta(0)=-\dfrac 12\;$ provides a simple answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the limit exists, the inner sum had better exist for $x < 1$. Does it?

Comment: SImple, elegant and to the point. +1